# Is there a term for a person who believes one race is superior to the others but not necessarily that race should rule all others?

Tags: single-word-requests

Normally I would call someone who believes 1 race is the best a "racial supremacist", however this term is not strictly correct, as you need to believe 1 race should rule over the others. Of course, there is the term "racist" but that covers a whole lot of ground.

Is there a specific term for someone who believes in the superiority of a race?

Comment: Why do you think 'racist' is not suitable?

Comment: https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/racist

Comment: There are varying definitions of white supremacy:  the ADL includes that "white people have their own 'culture' that is superior to other cultures" and "white people are genetically superior to other people"; many white supremacists are racial separatists who don't want to rule non-whites, but to repatriate them https://www.adl.org/resources/glossary-terms/white-supremacy

Comment: @StuartF That is why this question is being asked, methinks -- the overbroad application (and the popularization) of *xyzzy supremacy*.

Comment: Never mind "supremacy"; that's all speculation. The correct term is **_racist_**. It applies to anyone who believes that humans are divided biologically into distinct races.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Like I said, racist is a broad term.

Comment: @gbeeduljqa - yes, and your quest for a narrower term may be in vain.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey It may well be but I won't know unless I ask, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this definition in a Wikipedia article:

> Supremacism is the belief that a certain group of people is superior to all others.[1] The supposed superior people can be defined by age, race, ethnicity, religion, sex, language, social class, ideology, nation, or culture, or belong to any other part of a particular population.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supremacism

A person who subscribes to this notion might not necessarily think they should oppress other groups or dominate them and "take over the world".

Comment: Thanks, I was under the impression that the idea that one race should rule is an integral part of racial supremacy. I guess I was mistaken!

Comment: I'll note that wikipedia cited MW website for this... which presently *doesn't* give that def. MW says "an advocate or adherent of group supremacy". And for the latter "the quality or state of being supreme, also : supreme authority or power". So it's a bit of stretch to get the wiki def from MW.

Comment: Also going deeper into MW: "supreme 1: highest in rank or authority; the supreme commander 2: highest in degree or quality"